# Why is gpu used when reading image from webcam using VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, video-capture

When I use cv::VideoCapture to read from web cam, my gpu shows 17% usage, which I don't know why. I always assume this is a pure cpu thing.

My system is Win10 with opencv 4.0. I tried to compile with and without cuda, both ended the same.

This is my gpu usage when idle:
[image: idle]

This is my gpu usage when reading from webcam:
[image: idle]

This is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat img;
    while (true)
    {
        cap.read(img);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What reason do you have to think that it would be a CPU thing?

Comment: OpenCV's Video Capture class is built around several 3rd party backends, several of which use GPU acceleration for encoding/decoding.

Comment: Because a GPU ("Graphics Processing Unit") is better at processing graphics than a CPU. And yes, most video sensor output needs a bunch of further processing to be human-interpretable.

Comment: @ThomasJager Because only "3D" block is used, while "copy", "encode" and "decode" show no usage, which usually means nothing is copied to gpu memory and no decoding/encoding is performed. I wonder if anything can be processed by gpu without copying to gpu memory first.

Comment: @TheBarrometer As shown in the screen shot "encode" and "decode" blocks show no usage, so I'm not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question here. Thanks to all your help to make me realize I have a misunderstanding in video capture.

The default backend for VideoCapture is cv::CAP_ANY which means auto-detected, and in my case cv::CAP_MSMF is used. After specifying the backend to cv::CAP_DSHOW there's no more GPU usage. The modified code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0, CAP_DSHOW);// HERE
    Mat img;
    while (true)
    {
        cap.read(img);
    }
}
```